# What "|=" operator means in Go?

Tags: go

I've found this operator `|=` and I'm wondering what it means

```
func getPageInfoMode(r *http.Request) (mode PageInfoMode) {
    for _, k := range strings.Split(r.FormValue("m"), ",") {
        if m, found := modeNames[strings.TrimSpace(k)]; found {
            mode |= m
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Same as it means in C: short for `mode = mode | m`.

Comment: It happens that I don't know C either. Am I supposed to learn C before Go?

Comment: I wouldn't if I were starting out now. But there's 1000x more info--specifications, tutorials, tricks--about C on the web than there is for go at this point, and many of the basic ideas are similar (like almost all of the operators).

Answer (score 3):

Is an inplace bitwise OR operator https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators.

There are many others:

```
+    &     +=    &=     &&    ==    !=        
-    |     -=    |=     ||    <     <=        
*    ^     *=    ^=     <-    >     >=        
/    <<    /=    <<=    ++    =     :=        
%    >>    %=    >>=    --    !            
&^   &^=
```

Comment: Interesting...most of them seem undocumented (except the comparison operators).